# Sites for mnesia database dimesioning

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I have searched so much on net but could not find a good document or site on mnesia database dimesioning.Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

The use of Mnesia in ejabberd is intended for easy to deploy corporate messaging service. If you ask question about volume, it means you should plug another of the available ejabberd backend.